# ¿Cómo corregir algunos valores de una hoja excel?

Tags: python

stoy intentando hacer un programa para dos cosas. La primera es poder rellenar mi hoja excel con los datos que me faltan (ya que tengo datos cada 5 minutos y por motivos de la recogida de los mismos hay algunos saltos temporales) y después necesito corregir algunos datos (que siempre están en el mismo rango de valores) y darle otro valor.
Os muestro un ejemplo de la hoja excel que utilizo:

> Measurement Time  Zona 2  Zona 3  Zona 4
>
> 13/05/2021 10:45  0   0   0
>
> 13/05/2021 10:50  0   0   0
>
> 13/05/2021 10:55  0   0   0
>
> 13/05/2021 11:00  0   0   8
>
> 13/05/2021 11:05  0   0   0
>
> 13/05/2021 11:10  0   0   0
>
> 13/05/2021 11:15  0   0   0
>
> 13/05/2021 11:20  0   0   0
>
> 13/05/2021 11:25  0   0   0
>
> 13/05/2021 11:30  0   0   0
>
> 13/05/2021 11:35  0   0   0
>
> 13/05/2021 11:40  0   0   0
>
> 13/05/2021 11:45  0   0   0
>
> 13/05/2021 11:50  0   0   0
>
> 13/05/2021 11:55  0   0   0
>
> 13/05/2021 12:00  15  0   0
>
> 13/05/2021 12:05  95  0   0
>
> 13/05/2021 12:10  84  0   0
>
> 13/05/2021 12:15  83  0   0
>
> 13/05/2021 12:20  83  0   0
>
> 13/05/2021 12:25  84  0   22
>
> 13/05/2021 12:30  83  0   0
>
> 13/05/2021 12:35  82  0   0
>
> 13/05/2021 12:40  84  38  0
>
> 13/05/2021 12:45  83  0   0
>
> 13/05/2021 12:50  82  0   0
>
> 13/05/2021 12:55  82  0   0
>
> 13/05/2021 13:00  82  0   0
>
> 13/05/2021 13:05  82  0   0
>
> 13/05/2021 13:10  83  0   0
>
> 13/05/2021 13:15  82  0   0
>
> 13/05/2021 13:20  82  0   0
>
> 13/05/2021 13:25  81  0   0
>
> 13/05/2021 13:30  81  0   0
>
> 13/05/2021 13:35  83  0   0
>
> 13/05/2021 13:40  81  0   0
>
> 13/05/2021 13:45  82  0   0
>
> 13/05/2021 13:50  81  0   0
>
> 13/05/2021 13:55  81  0   0
>
> 13/05/2021 14:00  73  13  0
>
> 13/05/2021 14:05  1   94  0
>
> 13/05/2021 14:10  0   84  0
>
> 13/05/2021 14:15  0   85  0
>
> 13/05/2021 14:20  0   84  0
>
> 13/05/2021 14:25  0   83  0

La primera parte la tengo más que solucionada y probada que funciona que es esta:

```py
import pandas as pd
import io

tabla = pd.read_excel('PAUTAS.CAUDAL.xlsx', sheet_name='Hoja1')

timestamp_inicio = "01/01/2011 00:00"
timestamp_end = "31/12/2012 23:55" 

tabla.index = pd.to_datetime(tabla["Measurement Time"])
tabla = tabla.drop("Measurement Time", axis=1)

rango_fechas = pd.date_range (start=timestamp_inicio, end=timestamp_end, freq="5min")


tabla = tabla.reindex (rango_fechas)
tabla.index.name = "Measurement Time"  # Hay que ponerle nombre que se perdió al reindexar

tabla.to_excel("resultado.xlsx", na_rep="NAN")
```

El problema viene en la segunda parte, cuando quiero cambiar los datos de tres columnas de mi archivo zona 2, zona 3 y zona 4. De vez en cuando, aparecen valores entre 90 y 100 que sé que no son verdaderos, y los quisiera cambiar por el valor real. Estoy utilizando lo siguiente:

```py
df=tabla
df.loc[pd.isna(df["zona 2"]), "zona 2"] = df[pd.isna(df["zona 2"])]["zona 2"].apply(
    lambda x: 83 if "90<=x<=100" else "x")
```

Es algo que he buscado porque no tengo mucha idea, y pensaba que me iba a ayudar pero no... ¿Alguien podría ayudarme?
Lo agradecería mucho.

He probado también a utilizar esto:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook import numpy as np import pandas as pd

wb = load_workbook('PAUTAS.CAUDAL.xlsx') sheet1 = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Hoja1') matriz = np.zeros((sheet1.max_row, sheet1.max_column))

for i in range(0,sheet1.max_row):
    for j in range(0,sheet1.max_column):
        if matriz[i,j]>=90 : matriz[i,j]=83
    else:  
        matriz[i,j]=sheet1.cell(row=i+1, column=j+1).value


Matriz2= pd.DataFrame(matriz).to_csv('resultado.csv')
```

Y tampoco tengo un resultado, ya que me devuelve todo como cero.
Espero que ahora se vea mejor todo.

Un cordial saludo.

Comment: Tienes algún error? No obtienes el resultado esperado? Podrías prescribir mejor tu problema?

Comment: El error es que no me hace nada, creo que entra en un bucle y no me responde. ¿Me podrían ayudar o darme alguna idea de como debería realizarse? Muchas gracias

Comment: He editado mi pregunta. Disculpad las molestias.

Comment: no entiendo muy bien como es que quieres reemplazar los valores

Comment: Ósea si el valor esta entre 90 y 100, lo quieres reemplazar por 83?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En primer lugar decir que la forma en que usas la lambda está mal

```py
df.loc[pd.isna(df["zona 2"]), "zona 2"] = df[pd.isna(df["zona 2"])]["zona 2"].apply(
    lambda x: 83 if "90<=x<=100" else "x")
```

1. estas colocando la condición entre comillas `""`
2. estas escogiendo los datos para luego reemplazarlos, donde estas repitiendo código, todo se puede hacer con el método `.apply()`

la forma correcta seria escoger solo las columnas necesarias ya sea con `.loc[]` o `.iloc[]` luego utilizar el método `.apply()` a la cual le pasaremos una lambda para cambiar el valor si esta en un rango de 90 a 100.

```py
df.loc[:,"Zona 2":"Zona 4"] = df.loc[:,"Zona 2":"Zona 4"].apply(lambda x: x.apply(lambda x: 83 if x in range(90,101) else x))
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por tu gran ayuda! Sabía que estaba haciendo algo mal pero no daba con la tecla. Ahora puedo corregir los picos que aparecen en mis datos gracias a la corrección que me has hecho. :)